# Changing date when time changes

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a MS Access and SQL question.

I have a column that displays date and time as "2022-02-25D23:45:00T".

Now, I want to add 30 minutes and, if necessary, change the date to the next day.

Adding 30 minutes works fine if I add a new column via DateAdd("n",30,mid([column],12,8)).

When the time then changes to the next day, I want to change the date as well. So if time jumps from 23:45:00 to 00:15:00, how do I add a day?

Comment: Any chance you could convert `[column]` from text to Date/Time datatype?  If so, `DateAdd()` could adjust both the date and time parts as needed.

Comment: Why is date/time stored in text field? Use an IIf() expression or a VBA custom function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```vb
? DateAdd("n", 30, CDate(Left(Replace("2022-02-25D23:45:00T", "D", " "), 19)))
26-02-2022 00:15:00 

' To also rebuild the formatted string:

? Format(DateAdd("n", 30, CDate(Left(Replace("2022-02-25D23:45:00T", "D", " "), 19))), "yyyy-mm-dd\Dhh:nn:ss\T")
"2022-02-26D00:15:00T"
```